# Wordpress unregister_setting function not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to unregister setting in wordpress reading options using the function unregister_setting like below:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', array($this, 'unregister_settings'), 999 );
public function unregister_settings() {
    unregister_setting( 'reading', 'posts_per_rss' );
}
```

It seems to be used correctly according to wp documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_setting/ but it doesn't work (nothing happens). Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards
Rafal

Comment: "nothing happens" - what do you think should happen?

Comment: well, the posts_per_rss option should be removed from reading settings screen.

Answer (score 0):

The function unregister_setting() is not for displaying/hiding the setting in settings pages. This function is just for registering/unregistering (to let WP know that  whether it should save that setting in each form submit or not).

To hide the setting from settings pages needs just one operation:

Remove corresponding add_settings_field() function from your code.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I didn't know, but I am trying to remove on of the wp default fields so I cannot remove add_setting_field() function from my code. Any idea how to do that? Thanks

Comment: You can do it with CSS (.classname {display:none} ). Because default fields are hardcoded in core files. (wp-admin/options-reading.php)